# ignite - java-jdbc integration

Tags: sql, jdbc, ignite

I am new to Ignite. I am trying to follow an example on how to run SQL through a JDBC connection.

One of the examples in Git talks about using the SQL COPY command to copy large set of data from a CSV file.

However, when I run the Java code as in the example:

```
executeCommand(conn, "COPY FROM '" +      
    IgniteUtils.resolveIgnitePath("examples/src/main/resources/sql/city.csv") + "' " +
                    "INTO City (ID, Name, CountryCode, District, Population) FORMAT CSV");
```

I get a syntax error saying that SQL parcing error COPY[*] FROM ....

I tried to execute the same SQL from GridGain's console, I got the exact same error saying SQL Syntax error.

Could someone help me pointing what could be the issue here?

Environment

Platform: Ignite 2.4.0/CENTOS 6.7

IDE:Eclipse Kepler

JDK: 1.8

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace, and include a link to the example you're following so we can reference it if we need more context.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality was added in Ignite 2.5. You need to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks. I had difficulty finding the migration guide from ignite 2.4 to 2.6. Could you please help pointing to? I could try installing the 2.6 from scratch and copy the configuration file from 2.4. However, I would like to know if there is a proper migration guide to do this.

Comment: These versions are fully compatible on API level, so most likely you won't need to do any changes.